'Axios' doesn't request again after token refresh - react native
I'm using axios with React Native
I send request with accessToken to create profile.
So I made axiosInstace and I put 'Authorization' (accessToken).
The problem is, axios request failed after token refreshed.
->
Before accessToken is expired, axios works well.
However when the accessToken is expired, the error comes with status code 401 so my code reissue an accessToken.
Still, reissuing accessToken works!!
However, after reissuing accessToken, sending a new request doesn't work.
I'm not sure why it doesn't work.
Can you please help me?


import axios from 'axios';
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';

const baseURL = '-';
const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL });

let _refreshingPromise = null;

const reissueToken = async () => {
    try {
        const refreshToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

        if (!refreshToken) {
            throw new Error("refreshToken doesnt exist");
        }

        const response = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/auth/renew`, { refreshToken });

        const newAccessToken = response.data.accessToken;
        await EncryptedStorage.setItem('accessToken', newAccessToken);

        return newAccessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("reissue failed ", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        try {
            const accessToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('accessToken');
            config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            config.headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;

            console.log("original requests config:", config);
            return config;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("request interceptor failed:", error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error("request interceptor error :", error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);


axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        console.log("request succeed!");
        return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
        const { config,response } = error;
        const status = response? response.status : null;

    
        console.log("response status code : ", status);
        if(status === 502) {
            console.log("502 error");
            
        }
        if (status === 401) {
            console.log("start!");
            if (!_refreshingPromise) {
                console.log(_refreshingPromise);
                _refreshingPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    reissueToken()
                        .then((newAccessToken) => {
                            console.log("newToken : ", newAccessToken);
                            config.headers['Authorization'] = newAccessToken;
                            console.log(config.headers.Authorization);

                            axios(config)
                            .then((response) => {
                                
                                console.log("response:", response.data);
                                resolve(response); 
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log("request failed!");
                                reject(error); 
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                _refreshingPromise = null;
                            });
                        })
                        .catch((reissueError) => {
                            reject(new Error('error', reissueError));
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            _refreshingPromise = null;
                        });
                });
            }

            return _refreshingPromise;
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;



I tried change axios version. - now it is v1.6.8

made new Promise to have only 1 request.



I mean. Where should I start? Let's start with the basic one: 'refreshToken doesn't exist' Well - this should be either in double quotes or you should escape your apostrophe with ' - and it goes pretty much through the rest of the code.  I don't understand. You clearly have  console.log("response status code : ", status);  with double quotes, and then:  console.log('request succeed!'); - My suggestion is to stick with one standard and do it that way

@mutantkeyboard Thx for comment! I changed the quote problem. Can you please check axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use() part?  When I see my console, it properly sends new request with new accessToken . However, from the server console (firebase) the profile is not changed.

try this axios.request(error.config) I am using axios 0.21.1
axios.interceptors.response.use(
(response) => response,
async function(error) {
    if (401 === error?.response?.status) {
        const accessToken = await reissueToken();
        if (accessToken) {
            error.config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
            return axios.request(error.config);
        }
    }
});

